# How to increment the input field names in the middle of them

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html

I am trying to implement this extend form function in my project. Since I am compiling with CakePHP naming convention, in my extend form I have 2 field names:
[Student][0][age]
[Student][0][grade]

The script doesn't work because it is appending the counter only at the end of a field name all alike like this: fieldName + counter, whereas I am trying to increment, as you might have guessed it, like this:
[Student][1][age]
[Student][1][grade]

[Student][2][age]
[Student][2][grade]

I am new to Javascript and hopefully someone can advise how to work this out.

HTML:

```
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />
<br /><br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group required"><label for="Student1Age">Age</label><input name="data[Student][0][age]" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" maxlength="11" type="text" id="Student1Age" required="required"/></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">  
        <div class="form-group required">
            <label for="Student1Grade">級別</label>
            <select name="data[Student][0][grade]" class="form-control" id="Student1Grade" required="required">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="1">Grade 1</option>
                <option value="2">Grade 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div></span>

    <span id="writeroot"></span><input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!" />
```

Javascript:

```
    var counter = 0;
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace this one line like follows.

Yours:

```
newField[i].name = theName + counter;
```

New one:

```
newField[i].name = "[Student][" + counter + "][" + theName + "]";
```

I made a working sample page out of your script. Check the following link.

http://sugunan.net/demo/extend_form.php

Comment: I realised that the field names are actually something like this: "data[Student][0][age]", so I added 'data' to the line accordingly: "data[Student][" + counter + "][" + theName + "]". But it still doesn't work.

Comment: if the answer helpfull you may make it as right answer.

Comment: Am I correct to say that the var theName above contains the entire field name as it fetches the whole string from the child node? So if we append : "data[Student][" + counter + "][" + theName + "]" theName would contain the whole string to be something like this?: data[Student][0][ data[Student][0][age] ]

Comment: "theName" taken from the field you have already place. For example in this field <input name="cd" value="title" /> "cd" will be taken in to the place. So as you said the first set of form elements need to be placed as reference. But in this case all field you see will be loaded by javascript. So no need to worry. All visible field will be created with same format as you expect. Check my url with firebug.

Comment: It is successful to implement the code when I use the demo form. But when I use mine, it seems that the field names can not be located as the console says undefined. I think it's because of the divs?

Comment: I moved the input out of the div and it works perfectly. Im afraid Im encountering another problem that the childNodes method does not work in this situation, if you are so kind to assist me on that too. Thanks so much for helping out this far.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help you already have provided!

Comment: It's the html code that I posted in the post. Since I am using bootstrap grid I have lots of divs and the script is not able to find the input fields that are within the divs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904133/childnode-method-cannot-find-my-field-names.

@sugunan I have posted this question as a new post. Perhaps it's easier for you to answer it there. Thanks so much.