# childNodes method cannot find my field names

Tags: javascript, html

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html

I am trying to implement this extend form function in my project. But the field names cannot be located (the console log returns "undefined"), until I place an input field out of the divs and directly under the parent span tag. I'm not sure how the field names can be located and named accordingly as I intend to keep the divs.

HTML:

```
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review"
   onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">
  <br><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="Student1Age">Age</label>
        <input name="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age"
         maxlength="11" type="text" id="Student1Age" required="required">
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">  
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="Student1Grade">Grade</label>
        <select name="grade" class="form-control" id="Student1Grade" required="required">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Grade 1</option>
          <option value="2">Grade 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
<span id="writeroot"></span>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields()"
 value="Give me more fields!">
```

Javascript:

```
var counter = 0;
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name;
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = "data[Student][" + counter + "][" + theName + "]";
            console.log(newField[i].name);
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}
```

Comment: Is it breaking any of your functionality? or do you think undefined as an issue. Because console not necessary. it is just a function to debug the code. we can even remove it.

Comment: Yes it is. If the field names are not defined correctly the data cannot be saved I'm afraid.

Comment: The markup is invalid, a div isn't allowed inside a span. Change the outer span to a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childNodes` returns only direct children. It will find only elements with `name` attributes at the **top** level.  To find all descendant elements with names as you want, try

```
var newField = newFields.querySelectorAll('[name]');
```

Minor points:

1. Although in this case you don't need to use either, you should use `.children` instead of `.childNodes`. The latter will visit white-space nodes, which won't hurt anything but isn't what you want.
2. You are missing brackets around the body of the `if (theName)` statement, meaning the console.log is being executed each time through the loop, even when a white-space node is being visited. To avoid such problems, set up your editor to indent property, and/or run a linter across your code.

   ```
   if (theName) {
       newField[i].name = "data[Student][" + counter + "][" + theName + "]";
       console.log(newField[i].name);
   }
   ```
3. I'd suggest naming your variables a bit more clearly. You have a variable named `newFields` which is a single span, and you have a variable called `newField` which is a collection of fields.

Comment: The querySelectorAll() method finds the first input, age, but cannot find the grade input.

Comment: The selector should include the select element too, unless you're OK with them all having the same name.

Comment: Changed selector to `[name]` to pick up both input and select.

Comment: Thanks. I am totally new to Javascript. Thanks for putting up with me!